# In a 2-arm clinical trial where ten centers recruited patients, how does one test that two distributions are statistically similar?

Tags: r, distributions, clinical-trials

There are two arms in a clinical trial. If ten centers recruited subjects. How do I test in R that distribution across centers into two arms are statistically same? The distribution appears exponential where one center recruited 50% into each arm and the next two highest recruiting centers had 10% in each arm.

In R

`ks.test(arm1$Site, arm2$site)`

produced ks distance of .11 and a p value of .54

Comment: What kind of data is in the variable `site` ?

Comment: In general equivalence tests

Comment: What decision are you going to make on the basis of this test, what's its purpose? Did you expect the centers to recruit similar number of patients? Are they of similar size and serving similar populations of patients? I also suggest you read Ch. 14 "Multicentre Trials" of S. Senn's "Statistical Issues in Drug Development".

Comment: @RobertLong : As subjects are randomized into the trial the central data repository center keeps track of the center that randomized the subject (site:1:10) and which arm (arm1 or arm2) they went into.

Comment: @dipetkov: I want to test if there is a general trend to recruit the subjects into arm1 and not recruit into arm2 at one site or the other.  I am checking  if the recruiters somehow are favoring one arm.

Comment: It seems you want to check if the randomization has failed or the recruiters are following the protocol. A statistical test is not helpful here, esp. if its power is low. (A topic not discussed in the answer by @RobertLong but you might want to read about that too.) Why I don't think a statistical test is esp. convincing here: (a) If you fail to reject the null, maybe it's because of low power (you don't mention anything about sample size). (b) If you reject the null, then what? Does this tell you which center(s) have violated the protocol and do you actually have proof of that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have numeric data in the variable `site`, the first thing I would do is to inspect the histograms for this variable in each arm and do a simple "visual test", as documented in

> Buja, A., Cook, D. Hofmann, H., Lawrence, M. Lee, E.-K., Swayne,
> D.F and Wickham, H. (2009) Statistical Inference for exploratory
> data analysis and model diagnostics Phil. Trans. R. Soc. A 2009
> 367, 4361-4383 doi: 10.1098/rsta.2009.0120

Essentially, if you (and others if possible) cannot tell the difference then this is evidence the the distributions are very similar. Obviously the people comparing should be blinded as to which histogram is which.

**Formal Statistical Tests:** Nonparametric tests are often more robust when dealing with unequal group sizes and neither the Mann-Whitney U test or the Kolmogorov–Smirnov test *require* equal sample sizes, so you can also consider these. You have already run the K-S test and according to the result (p = 0.54) you cannot reject the null hypothesis that the data come from different distributions.